# Run Laravel Mix without a global nodejs and npm installation

Tags: node.js, npm, laravel-mix

I have a laravel project and I need to build styles and scripts with laravel-mix, but a testing server (Ubuntu 20.04.4) hasn't a globally installed node. Node and npm are in different folders in the system so I run commands like this:

```
/path/to/node /path/to/npm install
/path/to/node /path/to/npm run dev
```

But when I run `npm run dev` (this command runs laravel-mix build), I see the error:

```
> mazer@2.0.0 dev
> mix

/usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory
```

In the package.json it looks like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "mix"
    ...
}
```

I checked the laravel-mix package (in node_modules) and found this: `#!/usr/bin/env node`. The package checks the node var in this file, but there is no node var.

I don't need to change the env file, so how can I change this path or set a temporary system var? Is there any way to simulate that the variable is there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue with Docker, so now I run this command on git push:
`docker run --rm -v /path/to/project:/var/www/html node:16.16.0-alpine npm run dev --prefix /var/www/html`

Perhaps it will be useful to someone.

**UPD**

I found another way to resolve it, I use PATH incorrectly and for this reason it didn't work:

**Wrong**

I set paths to node and npm and then add it to PATH like this:

```
NODE_PATH="/path/to/node_folder/node"
NPM_PATH="/path/to/node_folder/npm"

PATH="${NODE_PATH}:${NPM_PATH}:$PATH"
```

And the system can't find npm and node anyway.

**The right way**

Add `/path/to/node_folders` (node and npm are in it) to PATH:

```
NODE_DIR="/path/to/node_folder"

PATH="${NODE_DIR}:$PATH"
```

And then, I can run just `npm install` and `npm run dev` without full paths to them.

Answer (score 0):

I have one solution for this problem.

The issue regarding naming misspelling or path symlinks.

so that you need to link symlinks for nodejs with this command

```
ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

or

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

Comment: Hi. I don't need to update the path of the global node, for some reasons so I now use docker to build my files.